# What is data transfer out in Amazon Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

In Amazon calculator for Glacier there's a section of data transfer out. When does this fee applies? I understand that data transfer out relating to EC2 means the bandwidth of data that people will download from my server on EC2. But what does it have to do with Glacier??

For example, if I download my backup file via FastGlacier (Windows Client for Amazon Glacier) to my personal PC will I be charged for the data transfer fees in addition to data retrieval fees? If not, in what Glacier related scenario does a data transfer out fee apply?

I tried to contact Amazon support but couldn't understand much from their answers.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Transfer fees will be applied when you

1. Transfer from glacier in one region to another AWS region
2. You Transfer from Glacier across the internet, for example to you PC

As you can see from the table below the first GB / Month is free and you start to pay above that.

[image]

Of course you always pay the Retrieval and Request costs.

More information can be found here:

https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/pricing/

Hope this helps,

Mike.

Comment: I knew I'm going to get here an answer to the point, unlike all the misleading and ambigous information that the Amazon support team gave me. Thank you!